# Add single key value to mysql table from python

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I'm trying to add just a single value to mysql table from python. I've tried about five different methods but I still get the error saying that the other keys in my table aren't being passed values when I call insert. The thing is I don't want to insert any other values, just to one specific key. Heres the code I currently have, and thanks in advance for you help

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM SONG")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        sname = str(input("What is the name of the song you are looking for: "))
        for row in result:
            title = row[0]
            if(title == sname):
                sql = ("INSERT INTO USER (s_id) VALUES (%s)")
                val = row[1]
                cursor.execute(sql, (val,))
```

mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1364 (HY000): Field 'userid' doesn't have
a default value

```
CREATE TABLE USER
(username   VARCHAR(20),
userid      CHAR(3),
a_id        CHAR(3),
s_id        CHAR(3),
PRIMARY KEY (userid),
FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES ALBUM(a_id),
FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES SONG(s_id));
CREATE TABLE PLAYLIST
(p_name     VARCHAR(20),
p_id        CHAR(3)         NOT NULL,
userid      CHAR(3),
s_id        CHAR(3),
PRIMARY KEY (p_id),
FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES USER(userid),
FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES SONG(s_id));
```

Comment: "The thing is I don't want to insert any other values, just to one specific key"—are the other fields nullable? Your database may be protecting you from making a data integrity error.

Comment: "I still get the error saying that the other keys in my table aren't being passed values when I call insert"—please [edit] your question and paste the _exact, complete_ error message into it.

Comment: The values are not set to not null so yes, the actual error I get is: Field 'userid' doesn't have a default value

Comment: If you don't provide values to insert, they are null. And fields must be _nullable_ to accept null values. The error indicates that your `userid` field is not nullable, and therefore cannot accept a null value. Either provide a value for `userid` (and any other non-nullable fields) or make them nullable.

Comment: I made them nullable, I will include my mysql code if you would like to see it

Comment: You also made `userid` your primary key. Primary keys cannot be null. See the first linked duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

The correct method will be not to use python for that, but just MySQL query to do that

```
    sname = str(input("What is the name of the song you are looking for: "))
    sql = ("INSERT INTO USER (s_id) select id from SONG where name= '%s'")
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: That's good advice, but not relevant to the error OP is facing. They'll get the same error.